Invalid Heap Arguments errors when using components from Boost Libraries in C++?
I'm using many boost libraries in my software application and After running a test case with Dr. Memory here there are 81 Invalid Heap argument errors mostly emitted from boost::log library and its use. Is there something that I might be doing wrong in implementing boost::log or is it a problem with the library itself?
These are the statistics of my memory assessment -

ERRORS FOUND:
      0 unique,     0 total unaddressable access(es)
      0 unique,     0 total uninitialized access(es)
     81 unique,   137 total invalid heap argument(s)
      0 unique,     0 total GDI usage error(s)
      0 unique,     0 total handle leak(s)
      0 unique,     0 total warning(s)
      6 unique,     6 total,    532 byte(s) of leak(s)
      0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of possible leak(s)
ERRORS IGNORED:
      4 potential error(s) (suspected false positives)
         (details: C:\Users\Sagun Khosla\AppData\Roaming\Dr. Memory\DrMemory-ZoneSystemTest.exe.28660.000\potential_errors.txt)
     20 unique,    20 total,  12520 byte(s) of still-reachable allocation(s)
         (re-run with "-show_reachable" for details)
Details: C:\Users\Sagun Khosla\AppData\Roaming\Dr. Memory\DrMemory-ZoneSystemTest.exe.28660.000\results.txt

And here is an example of the boost::log memory dump -
Error #81: INVALID HEAP ARGUMENT: allocated with operator new, freed with operator delete[]
# 0 replace_operator_delete_array_nothrow                                      [D:\a\drmemory\drmemory\common\alloc_replace.c:3002]
# 1 boost_log-vc143-mt-x64-1_84.dll!boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_pd<>::`scalar deleting destructor'
# 2 boost_log-vc143-mt-x64-1_84.dll!`boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::aux::lazy_singleton<>::get_instance'::`2'::`dynamic atexit destructor for 'instance''
# 3 ucrtbase.dll!_sys_nerr                                                    +0x2b2    (0x00007ffdb5623a93 <ucrtbase.dll+0x53a93>)
# 4 ucrtbase.dll!o_free                                                       +0xdd     (0x00007ffdb55f042e <ucrtbase.dll+0x2042e>)
# 5 ucrtbase.dll!execute_onexit_table                                         +0x3c     (0x00007ffdb55edddd <ucrtbase.dll+0x1dddd>)
# 6 ntdll.dll!LdrpCallInitRoutine
# 7 ntdll.dll!LdrShutdownProcess
# 8 ntdll.dll!LdrShutdownProcess
# 9 ntdll.dll!RtlExitUserProcess
#10 KERNEL32.dll!ExitProcessImplementation
#11 ucrtbase.dll!exit                                                         +0xb7     (0x00007ffdb55ebed8 <ucrtbase.dll+0x1bed8>)
#12 ucrtbase.dll!exit                                                         +0x278    (0x00007ffdb55ec099 <ucrtbase.dll+0x1c099>)
#13 ZoneSystemTest.exe!?                                                      +0x0      (0x00007ff7223a2553 <ZoneSystemTest.exe+0x3b2553>)
#14 ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart
Note: @0:00:12.071 in thread 20264
Note: memory was allocated here:
Note: # 0 replace_operator_new                                                       [D:\a\drmemory\drmemory\common\alloc_replace.c:2903]
Note: # 1 boost_log-vc143-mt-x64-1_84.dll!boost::detail::shared_count::shared_count<> [C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\smart_ptr\detail\shared_count.hpp:219]
Note: # 2 boost_log-vc143-mt-x64-1_84.dll!boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::aux::lazy_singleton<>::get [C:\vcpkg\buildtrees\boost-log\src\ost-1.84.0-de692694bc.clean\include\boost\log\detail\singleton.hpp:45]
Note: # 3 boost_log-vc143-mt-x64-1_84.dll!boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::attribute_name::get_id_from_string [C:\vcpkg\buildtrees\boost-log\src\ost-1.84.0-de692694bc.clean\src\attribute_name.cpp:189]
Note: # 4 boost_log-vc143-mt-x64-1_84.dll!boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::aux::lazy_singleton<>::get [C:\vcpkg\buildtrees\boost-log\src\ost-1.84.0-de692694bc.clean\include\boost\log\detail\singleton.hpp:45]
Note: # 5 boost_log-vc143-mt-x64-1_84.dll!boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::aux::default_attribute_names::severity [C:\vcpkg\buildtrees\boost-log\src\ost-1.84.0-de692694bc.clean\src\default_attribute_names.cpp:81]
Note: # 6 boost_log-vc143-mt-x64-1_84.dll!boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::sinks::aux::default_sink::default_sink [C:\vcpkg\buildtrees\boost-log\src\ost-1.84.0-de692694bc.clean\src\default_sink.cpp:193]
Note: # 7 boost_log-vc143-mt-x64-1_84.dll!boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::core::implementation::implementation [C:\vcpkg\buildtrees\boost-log\src\ost-1.84.0-de692694bc.clean\src\core.cpp:303]
Note: # 8 boost_log-vc143-mt-x64-1_84.dll!boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::aux::lazy_singleton<>::get [C:\vcpkg\buildtrees\boost-log\src\ost-1.84.0-de692694bc.clean\include\boost\log\detail\singleton.hpp:45]
Note: # 9 boost_log-vc143-mt-x64-1_84.dll!boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::core::get          [C:\vcpkg\buildtrees\boost-log\src\ost-1.84.0-de692694bc.clean\src\core.cpp:502]
Note: #10 ZoneSystemTest.exe!?                                                      +0x0      (0x00007ff72200603f <ZoneSystemTest.exe+0x1603f>)
Note: #11 ZoneSystemTest.exe!?

Minimal Reproduceable Example -
/*
 *          Copyright Andrey Semashev 2007 - 2015.
 * Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0.
 *    (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
 *          http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
 */

#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE "LoggingTest"

// Setting this to 0x0602 (Windows 8) or higher will cause linking to fail.
// It works with 0x0601 (Windows 7).
#define  _WIN32_WINNT   0x0602

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_file_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;

#if 0

//[ example_tutorial_file_simple
void init()
{
    logging::add_file_log("sample.log");

    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );
}
//]

// We need this due to this bug: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4416
//[ example_tutorial_file_advanced_no_callouts
void init()
{
    logging::add_file_log
    (
        keywords::file_name = "sample_%N.log",
        keywords::rotation_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024,
        keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0),
        keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%]: %Message%"
    );

    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );
}
//]

#else

//[ example_tutorial_file_advanced
void init()
{
    logging::add_file_log
    (
        keywords::file_name = "sample_%N.log",                                        /*< file name pattern >*/
        keywords::rotation_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024,                                   /*< rotate files every 10 MiB... >*/
        keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0), /*< ...or at midnight >*/
        keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%]: %Message%"                                 /*< log record format >*/
    );

    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );
}
//]

#endif

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(LoggingTest)
{
    init();
    logging::add_common_attributes();

    using namespace logging::trivial;
    src::severity_logger< severity_level > lg;

    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, trace) << "A trace severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, debug) << "A debug severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, info) << "An informational severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, warning) << "A warning severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, error) << "An error severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, fatal) << "A fatal severity message";
}



A [mre] would help us to help you

No, that is very unlikely. It is much more likely that the operator delete[] mismatch stems from your code. Please show a [mre]. It is completely pointless to speculate without one.

But the stack dump generates over code that I have no control over. The minimal reproducible example is simple and I've added it to the post.

Sorry, I didn't read the stack trace carefully enough. It says "scalar deleting destructor" to be the culprit. That is a compiler-generated function that always should call operator delete, not operator delete[]. I don't know why your tool claims that it calls operator delete[]. I don't know for sure, but would tend to say that the tool has a bug.

See e.g. https://github.com/DynamoRIO/drmemory/issues/2339, https://github.com/DynamoRIO/drmemory/issues/1874.
